# ifelse statement inside apply returns unexpected result

Tags: r

I am trying to use an `ifelse` statement inside `apply` and am getting an odd result.  I get the expected answer if the variable `marker` is `1`, but not when that variable is `> 9`.

Here is an example data set for which I get the correct answer:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
   REFNO   status    stage   marker   cumulative   newstage
 1018567      ccc       AA        0             1         AA
 1018567      aaa     NONE        0             1       NONE
 1018567      aaa       BB        1             1         BB
 1018567      bbb       CC        1             1         CC
 1018567      eee       CC        1             1         CC
 1018567      mmm       CC        1             1         CC
 1018567      ppp       CC        1             1         CC
 1019711      ddd       CC        1             1         CC
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my.data$newstage <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) ifelse(x['status'] == 'aaa'  & 
                                          x['stage']      == 'NONE' & 
                                          x['marker']     == 0      & 
                                          x['cumulative'] > 0, 'BB', x['stage']))

my.data
```

The data set below differs in only one element from that above, but I do not obtain the correct answer.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
   REFNO   status    stage   marker    cumulative   newstage
 1018567      ccc       AA        0             1         AA
 1018567      aaa     NONE        0             1       NONE
 1018567      aaa       BB        1             1         BB
 1018567      bbb       CC        1             1         CC
 1018567      eee       CC        1             1         CC
 1018567      mmm       CC        1             1         CC
 1018567      ppp       CC        1             1         CC
 1019711      ddd       CC       14             1         CC
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my.data$newstage <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) ifelse(x['status'] == 'aaa'  & 
                                          x['stage']      == 'NONE' & 
                                          x['marker']     == 0      & 
                                          x['cumulative'] > 0, 'BB', x['stage']))

my.data
```

Thank you for any suggestions.  Perhaps I should be using an `if` statement instead of an `if-else`?

Specifically, I would like `NONE` to be replaced with `BB` for `newstage` in the second row.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but if you look at `apply(my.data2, 1, function(x) x)` The marker column has two characters instead of one because of the two digit 14 in the marker column.  This produces `" 0" == 0` in your code, which is `FALSE`.  However, `"0" == 0` is `TRUE`

Comment: Why can't you use  `with(my.data, ifelse(status=='aaa' & stage=='NONE' & !marker & cumulative >0, 'BB', stage))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at `apply(my.data2, 1, function(x) x)`, the `marker` column has two characters instead of one.  This is because of the two digit `14`. The coercion to character pads the column with spaces to the length of its longest (most characters) element.  This produces `" 0" == 0` in your code, which is `FALSE`. However, `"0" == 0` is `TRUE`

```
" 0" == 0
# [1] FALSE
"0" == 0
# [1] TRUE
```

Since `ifelse` is vectorized, you don't need to use `apply` at all. You could add the new column with `within` (or `with`, as akrun mentions) or simply with `newstage <- ifelse(...)`

```
within(my.data2, {
    newStage <- ifelse(status == "aaa" & stage == "NONE" & marker == 0 & 
                           cumulative > 0, "BB", stage)
})
#     REFNO status stage marker cumulative newstage newStage
# 1 1018567    ccc    AA      0          1       AA       AA
# 2 1018567    aaa  NONE      0          1     NONE       BB
# 3 1018567    aaa    BB      1          1       BB       BB
# 4 1018567    bbb    CC      1          1       CC       CC
# 5 1018567    eee    CC      1          1       CC       CC
# 6 1018567    mmm    CC      1          1       CC       CC
# 7 1018567    ppp    CC      1          1       CC       CC
# 8 1019711    ddd    CC     14          1       CC       CC
```

Comment: Yes.  This is much better coding practice on the whole.

Comment: Excellent.  I should have known this.

Answer (score 3):

So when you use apply as you are, the function converts `my.data` to a character matrix.  When this happens, as Richard Scriven points out in the comments, you end up with the `marker` column having an extra sapce in it.  When you run your comparison the `numeric`s are converted to `character`s and don't have this extra space and so return `FALSE`.

Converting to `numeric` in your `apply` will fix this.

```
my.data$newstage <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) ifelse(x['status']     == 'aaa'  & 
                                                       x['stage']      == 'NONE' & 
                                                       as.numeric(x['marker'])     == 0      & 
                                                       as.numeric(x['cumulative']) > 0, 'BB', x['stage']))
```

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.  I keep forgetting that `apply` converts to `matrix`.